# Using jsdoc @type imports in LWC crashes page when "Debug Mode"

Tags: lightning-web-components, jsdoc

Is anyone successfully able to use [jsdoc `@type imports`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#import-types) for LWC components?

According to this [guide it should be possible](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/04/how-to-use-typescript-with-salesforce-part-2), but when I add `@type {import ...}` and NOTHING else, my the entire page crashes with some cryptic error:

```js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class TestJsDoc extends LightningElement {
    /** @type {import('./types').Props} */
    props;
}
```

[image]

> possible import expression rejected around line 93 [possible import expression rejected around line 93]

I delete the line and it works again...

Are LWC really so fragile that adding a comment causes them to crash?!

### Update

- Determine that it only happens if [Debug Mode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/debug-mode-enable.html) is turned on for my user.
- Enabling/Disabling LWS doesn't seem to have any impact

Comment: Took me about an hour to figure out this is what was going on... Reverted all my code until finally all I had left is comments :(

Comment: It works in my org. When does this error appear for you? Saving? Deployment? While running? Have you tried updating to the latest CLI version?

Comment: It crashed when the component is on a page layout "tab".  It's a complicated app so maybe it's in combination with something else.  I was attempting to retroactively add typings (desperately needs them). 

I'll try to create a Minimal Reproducible Example

Comment: Was able to reproducible... Added then line to an empty component and then added that component to a custom object page with nothing else.  

The path doesn't actually resolve a file, but it seems like it never would when deployed to salesforce...

Comment: Hmm, okay. Still not getting it. Does enabling Lightning Web Security make it go away?

Comment: I just disabled "LWC Debug Mode" for my user and now it's working...

Comment: Odd. I'm using debug mode as well. It may be a combination of LWS, API version, and debug mode. I think you're on the right track, though.

Comment: I tried turning on LWS.  With debug mode on, it's still crashing... I also set up the example with a valid import path to another LWC just to double-check (still crashes)

Comment: I just got similar issue, in my Dev Org all good. In a Sandbox, created from our EE it fails. I use it with the 'lightning/platformResourceLoader'

Comment: Can you check if it works if you use for start of comment: '/*!'